# How to Find subapths in url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url, spring-rest

URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com/stackoverflow/question");

### OUPUT

path1=stackoverflow,
path2=question,

### ANOTHER

URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com/stackoverflow/question/java");

### OUTPUT

path1=question
path2=java

If we enter dynamic url than how we can find the paths like this.
Thanks

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the code below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   URL aURL = new URL("http://www.google.com/stackoverflow/question");
    String[] pathSplit = aURL.getPath().split("/");
    System.out.println("path1 = " + pathSplit[1]);
    System.out.println("path2 = " + pathSplit[2]);
}
```